# MySQL Relationships with historical data

Tags: mysql

Prior to MySQL I've been using static CSVs to produce dashboards (currently PowerBI, doing a course to build out in Python) displaying data on a cloud environment. The CSVs (Compute / Storage) are split out into 5 tables connected per the image attached.

[image: Table Setup]

[image: Table Setup in MySQL (from MySQL Reverse Engineer option)]

However moving to MySQL would allow me to load in these CSVs regularly - so I've setup a Python script which does this daily. Prior to importing into MySQL, it appends the date/time as a 'Report Date' column. This is where I seem to be having issues, doing this breaks the relationships as now 'Cluster Name', for instance, is no longer unique.

What is the best approach to dealing with this situation? Currently I have setup the primary key as both the date AND the unique names, with foreign keys connecting the tables together. Is this the correct way to go, or am I missing something that would make dealing with the 'duplicate' data (minus the dates) easier? (Unfortunately anything I Google about Dates seems to be about the Data Type 'DATETIME', than practically handling dates)

Comment: What are your concerns regarding the inclusion of the date field in the pk?

Comment: My main concern is how I can maintain my existing setup of 1-many relationships while introducing the date field into the mix - doing so removes the unique values, I could add merged date/unique name columns into each table? Perhaps this is perfectly okay to do, and it's more the dashboard (PowerBI / Python) end where I'll need to figure out a way to visualise the data.

Comment: This really depends on your requirements, there is no universally valid answer! If you need to store the historical data in one table, then you need to add the date (or any other value indicating the various uploads) to the primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Define each object as a table.  Then relations as link tables.  The date can be kept in the link tables.

```
Cluster     name
Host        name
Datastore   name
Disk        name
Instance    name
```

Then relations:

```
Cluster_has_host     cluster_name, host_name, date
Host_has_Instance    host_name, instance_name, date
and so on
```

This way you can store your objects as single entities, and date the relations instead of the objects.

You have to think of your data model like this:

- objects and their attributes are tables
- relations are link tables
- attributes of the relations go in the link tables

---

One example where some confusion could arise is this.  What of the disk size?  You could...

1. Define one disk object per size.  This assumes a disk is of a fixed size and cannot vary.
2. Add the disk size to the Datastore_has_disk.  This way on a certain date you will know what size the disk was.  This assumes your disks can change in size.

This is decided by how you view your data.  Is the disk the object, or the "disk of a certain size" the object?  This you have to figure out for yourself, based on your requirements.